# Como mapear o valor de 2 inputs em React?

Tags: javascript, react, formulário, input, map

estou criando uma espécie de TodoList em React e tive a ideia de utilizar dois inputs.

O código é dividido em 3 componentes:

`App.js:`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import Modal from './Modal'

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [value2,setValue2] = useState("")
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const getValue = (event)=>{
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const getValue2=(event)=>{
    setValue2(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Form 
      valueProp={value} 
      valueProp2={value2}
      onChangeProp={getValue}
      onChangeProp2={getValue2}
      typeProp="submit"
      handleSubmitProp={(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setTodos([...todos, value]);
      }}/>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, index) => (
          <li key={index}><Modal title={todo} content={value2}/></li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`Form.js:`

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Form({valueProp,valueProp2,typeProp,onChangeProp,onChangeProp2,handleSubmitProp}){
  return(
    <>
    <form onSubmit = {handleSubmitProp}>
      <input value = {valueProp} onChange={onChangeProp}/>
      <input value = {valueProp2} onChange={onChangeProp2}/>
      <button type={typeProp}>ENTER</button>
    </form>
      
    </>
  )
}
```

`Modal.js:`

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Modal({title,content}){
  return(
    <>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

O problema dessa aplicação é que quando os itens (colocados no input) aparecem na tela acontecem o seguinte:

- A propriedade `title` quando renderizada fica imutável após o submit (que é o que eu quero).
- Já a propriedade `content`, quando renderizada não fica imutável, pois ao mexer novamente no input ela se altera, seguindo o valor do segundo input.

Para deixar mais claro irei colocar uma imagem:

[image: Essa é a situação da tela após o submit:]

Essa é a situação da tela após eu dar o submit, aparentemente normal.

[image: Essa é a situação da tela após eu alterar o input]

Essa é a situação da tela após eu alterar o valor do input (sem dar o submit de novo !), repare que o primeiro valor ficou inalterado mas o segundo se alterou.

Creio que o erro esteja na parte de mapear (linha 30 do `App.js`). Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema ? o que preciso fazer para que o segundo valor do input fique imutável após a renderização ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está em `<Modal title={todo} content={value2}/>`, ele faz referência direta ao estado de `value2` em `content={value2}`, logo, qualquer alteração nesse estado será refletida no `Modal`.

Analisando o sua pergunta, me parece que sua ideia é do primeiro input ser o `title` e o segundo ser o `content`. Se for isso mesmo que estou pensando, a minha dica é você criar um objeto da seguinte forma:

```
{ title: value, content: value2 }
```

Isso daria uma semântica maior, além de fazer com que `value2` não seja referênciado diretamente no `Modal`, tornando o valor imutável dentro deste componente.

Na sua função de estado para o `todos` ficaria desta forma:

```
setTodos([...todos, { title: value, content: value2 }])
```

Agora na hora de renderizar o `Modal` ficaria desta forma:

```
{todos.map((todo, index) => (
  <li key={index}>
    <Modal title={todo.title} content={todo.content} />
  </li>
 ))}
```

Repare como ficou a lógica para o `Modal` para este renderizar o `title` e o `content`:

```
title={todo.title} content={todo.content}
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo do código (adaptado para executar no snippet do SO):

```js
function Form ({
  valueProp,
  valueProp2,
  typeProp,
  onChangeProp,
  onChangeProp2,
  handleSubmitProp
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmitProp}>
        <input value={valueProp} onChange={onChangeProp} />
        <input value={valueProp2} onChange={onChangeProp2} />
        <button type={typeProp}>ENTER</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

function Modal ({ title, content }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')
  const [value2, setValue2] = React.useState('')
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([])

  const getValue = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const getValue2 = event => {
    setValue2(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        valueProp={value}
        valueProp2={value2}
        onChangeProp={getValue}
        onChangeProp2={getValue2}
        typeProp='submit'
        handleSubmitProp={e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          setTodos([...todos, { title: value, content: value2 }])
        }}
      />
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <Modal title={todo.title} content={todo.content} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

<sup>Tive que substituir `<></>` por `<div></div>` e usar `React.useState` para o exemplo acima.</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado ! Sua solução ajudou demais !